# How to reload main class in java?

Tags: java, applet

Actually I am developing a game **TicTacToe**.In this game when the game ends my form disappears and I need to run it from command line arguments to play it once again.Actually in my logic if I can reload or run the main class then it will be very helpful for me to develop a good game. Actually as we know when a java program runs then main class will be called first. ****And my question is that What to do if we want to reload or want to run main class again?****Please help me as soon as possible I am waiting form reply.

Comment: are you loading it as an applet? Where are you executing it from? What do you mean by "my form disappears"?

Answer (score 3):

Let's imagine your main launches a function startGame(), just create a while loop.

```
While(true) startGame()
```

When your game ended, it will start again.

A better way to do this is to add a Menu, that returns true or false if the person wants to play another game.

```
while(showMenu()) {
   startGame();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your game is over you should add buttons to or replace the game window to provide a restart option.  When the user chooses this option you can repaint your game window and start it again.  The main method only provides a hook to start your application, the application itself needs to handle any retry logic.